# PHP session destroyed too soon on mobile browser(s)

Tags: php, android, session-cookies, session-timeout

I have the following issue. I am building a PHP + jQuery mobile website and I want to maintain the PHP session. 
The problem here is that when I close the browser App (Samsung Galaxy S4/S5 or Google Chrome on Android) and I leave the phone for say, ten minutes, and then reopen the browser, the whole session appears to be destroyed and I have to log in again.

I tried to increase the cookie lifetime like this:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 24);
ini_set('session.gc-maxlifetime', 60 * 60 * 24);
session_start();
```

But this does not solve it. I think it is because the browser app purges the session data after some time of inactivity.

Note that I do not want to use "remember me" functionality, I just want to use the PHP session ID.

What would be the correct way to solve this? I have looked at local storage but it seems strange the browser App purges the entire session and I am looking for the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it (after a lot of trying out) using the php.ini setting

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 3600
```

After doing this, the mobile browser kept the session alive. Even if I put my phone away for a longer period.

Apparently setting the maxlifetime does not work if done through a script.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to modify the ini values try using the [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) function like so:

```
session_set_cookie_params(60 * 60 * 24);
session_start();
```

Comment: tried it, it doesn't work. What happens is that the browser app disconnects from the PHP session (cookie) after the app goes inactive. So you can set the cookie on the server side, but once it is purged on the client there is no way to revive the session. Well not yet, this is what I am investigating.

Comment: Are other cookies preserved after the app goes inactive? If the answer is no then it is probably a setting or issue within the app and not PHP. edit: Speaking of, what browser app are you testing it in and have you tried others?

Comment: the $_SESSION is gone. Yes I have tried Google Chrome, a Samsung galaxy S4 and S5 and a Samsung tab3. All have the same issue.